# Неверное отображение серийного номера SSD диска

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Мне необходимо получить серийные номера различных устройств хранения данных. На данный момент написан код, корректно работающий с HDD, однако при работе с SSD функция возвращает не тот результат (`0000_0000_0100_0000_E4D2_5C42_46E3_4D01`), который я ожидаю.

Также пробовал использовать WMI, результат тот же.

Вопрос такой: корректно ли я использую данный код в применении к SSD. Возможно, есть ли какие-то другие решения, не стесняйтесь, пишите.

```
// HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", FILE_ANY_ACCESS ,
                         FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                         OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
// bool success = h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
std::string getSerialNumber(HANDLE h)
{


    std::string result;
    static STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery };
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSTR psz;
        PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
    };
    ULONG size = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR) + 0x100;
    ULONG dwError;
    do
    {
        dwError = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, size))
        {
            DWORD returned;
            if (DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq,
                sizeof(spq), buf, size, &returned, 0))
            {
                if (psdd->Version >= sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR))
                {
                    if (psdd->Size > size)
                    {
                        size = psdd->Size;
                        dwError = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (psdd->SerialNumberOffset)
                        {
                            result = psz + psdd->SerialNumberOffset;
                            dwError = NOERROR;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(ERROR_NO_DATA));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(ERROR_GEN_FAILURE));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(GetLastError()));
            }

            LocalFree(buf);
        }
    } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
    return result;
}
```

Пробовал получить данный серийный номер из Linux и UEFI - результат одинаковый, номер отображается корректно.

Также пытался получить данный серийный номер GUI средствами Windows - не смог найти решения (но номер необходимо получить именно программно).

Comment: ваш код корректно отработал на мои хардах. Получение SN `wmic diskdrive get model,name,serialnumber` WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  WD-WXP1A560K457. Ваш код выдает "     WD-WXP1A560K457". Лишние пробелы, но думаю это не критично.

Comment: можете добавить в вопрос вывод "wmic diskdrive get model,name,serialnumber" (выполнять в командной строке) и вывод вашего кода по проблемному устройству?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, лишние пробелы - решаемая проблема. на HDD отрабатывает корректно, неверно отображается номер SSD

Comment: @goldstar_labs, пробовал WMI - результат тот же

Comment: вот решение для power shell "Get-WMIObject win32_physicalmedia | Format-List Tag,SerialNumber"

Comment: @goldstar_labs, пробовал подобное решение в C++ коде как описано на MSDN (WQL) - результат тот же

Comment: может дело в ссд или интерпретации набора байтов? у меня была похожая ситуация с купюроприемником, когда производитель в своем ПО набор байтов, которые возвращает устройство, трактовал неправильно и отображал некорректный SN, хотя байты были одинаковые

Comment: Доп. вопрос :), какой номер вы получаете с вашим кодом? "0000_0000_0100_0000_E4D2_5C42_46E3_4D01" - это правильный?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, вероятнее всего, проблема в этом. в английском stackoverflow.com отписали также, что вероятнее всего проблема в драйвере устройства. спасибо за помощь

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я считаю этот номер неправильным, т. к. он не совпадает с тем, что получен в UEFI среде и Linux (в UEFI и Linux результаты одинаковые)

Comment: Александр, можете написать какую строку вы ожидаете?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, `BTPY72960UBX128A`

Comment: Может этот вопрос поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049367/how-do-i-get-the-disk-drive-serial-number-in-c-c https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: @Unick, данные решения используют WMI, мне не удалось получить то, что я ожидал с помощью данного инструмента, но всё равно спасибо